# Concatenate a pivot table output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following code that returns a pivoted table of current jobs and their estiamted times:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                    QUOTENAME(Name)
                  FROM JobPhases
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'SELECT *
FROM    
(   
    SELECT c.Registration as ''Reg.'', p.Name, [x] = j.EstimatedTime
    FROM    JobDetails  AS j
    INNER JOIN JobPhases p ON p.ID = j.PhaseId
    INNER JOIN Jobs job on job.ID = j.JobID
    INNER JOIN Cars c on job.CarID = c.ID
    WHERE job.Status = 1 or job.Status = 0
) JobDetails
PIVOT
(   SUM(x)
    FOR Name IN (' + @cols + ')
) pvt'

execute(@query);
```

Output:

```
JobID | Repair & Reshape | Refit Stripped Parts | Polishing 
1000  | 2.00             | 1.00                 | 1.30
1001  | 2.30             | 0.30                 | 2.00
```

What I need is to concatenate `j.ActualTime` in the displayed value. Any ideas how I can do this? So, the final output would be `- 4.00 / 5.30` (where 4.00 is `j.EstimatedTime` and 5.30 is `j.ActualTime`).

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do all of your processing first, outside of the PIVOT. This way you can do aggregations, concatenations, and whatever you want. After all the processing, then do a simple, non-aggregating pivot:

```
SELECT *
FROM    
(   
    SELECT c.Registration as ''Reg.'', p.Name, 
        CAST(SUM(j.EstimatedTime) as VARCHAR(MAX)) + '/' +
        CAST(SUM(j.ActualTime) as VARCHAR(MAX)) as [x]
    FROM    JobDetails  AS j
    INNER JOIN JobPhases p ON p.ID = j.PhaseId
    INNER JOIN Jobs job on job.ID = j.JobID
    INNER JOIN Cars c on job.CarID = c.ID
    WHERE job.Status = 1 or job.Status = 0
    GROUP BY c.Registration, p.Name
) JobDetails
PIVOT
(   MAX(x)
    FOR Name IN (' + @cols + ')
) pvt
```

Comment: This looks like it could work, however I am getting the error "Operand data type varchar(max) is invalid for sum operator." Obviously this is relating to lines 5 and 6, not being able to convert the sum to a varchar but I can't work out the solution? Cheers

Comment: @MattBaughan My bad. SUM doesn't work on character types, but MAX should. Let me know if that works for you.